# MIPS - Simple Addition - Input Storage Issue using Temp registers

Tags: assembly, mips

this is my first time writing an assembly program. I'm supposed to write a basic addition program using $t0, $t1 and $t2 to store the first two user inputs and the sum. I am having trouble understanding why my user input is always stored as 5.

Might there be an issue with my syscalls?

```
.data
prompt1: .asciiz "Give me an integer number: "
debug1: .asciiz "The first number inputted was: "
debug2: .asciiz "The second number inputted was: "
prompt2: .asciiz "\nGive me another integer number: "
result: .asciiz "\nThe sum of the two inputted numbers is: "

.text

li $v0, 4 #System call to print a string
la $a0, prompt1 #load prompt1 into address 0 - Give me an integer
syscall

#store first input in $t0
li $v0, 5 #System call code for Read Integer from input
move $t0, $v0 #Move value from $v0 to $t0
syscall 

#print the First user input for debugging --> Always prints 5

li $v0, 4  #System call code for Print String
la $a0, debug1 #Print debug1 string
syscall

li $v0, 1   #print int
move $a0, $t0   #move value in $t0 to $a0
syscall

#call prompt 2
li $v0, 4 #Print a string
la $a0, prompt2 # Here is the value to print - "Give me another integer"
syscall

#store second input in $t1
li $v0, 5 #System call code for Read Integer from input
move $t1, $v0 # $t1 = value from input
syscall

#print the second int input for debugging --> Always prints 5

li $v0, 4 #System call code for Print String
la $a0, debug2 #Print debug2 string
syscall

li $v0, 1   #System call code for Print Int
move $a0, $t1   #move value in $t1 to $a0
syscall

#add numbers
add $t2, $t1, $t0 # $t2 = $t1+$t0

li $v0, 4 #System call to Print String
la $a0, result #Print the string result 
syscall

li $v0, 1  #System call to Print Int
move $a0, $t2 #Move $t2, which = $t1 + $t0, into $a0
syscall
```

I appreciate the help in advance.

Comment: Did you check with a debugger to see what values are in registers?  You can make sure the return value of the read system call is what you expect, and make sure it ends up in the right place for later code.  (I don't know a lot of MIPS, and didn't notice anything wrong yet.)

Comment: Hey @PeterCordes yes I have, the $t0 and $t1 registers are always returning the value 5. It would appear this has something to do with the fact that the code for "Get Int From Input" is 5. Aka, "li $v0, 5". So the question is then why is $v0 not getting overwritten by the input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue --

```
#store second input in $t1
li $v0, 5 #System call code for Read Integer from input
syscall
move $t1, $v0 # $t1 = value from input
```

Should have a syscall after the *li* line, and **not** after the *move* line. Otherwise the value of $v0 gets moved to $t0, which is 5, without waiting for the user input to change the value of $v0. If you have a `syscall` after the `move` line, the program will executing another service call based on your user input. See more in the comments here : [Service Calls Executing Based on User Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39311412/service-calls-executing-based-on-user-input?noredirect=1#comment65955670_39311412)

Answer (score 1):

In mips `$t0` and `$t1` are temporary registers. According to its calling convention you can't make any assumptions about temporary register contents after you make a call. So unless the syscall specifically states otherwise you should assume it overwrites the temporary registers. Instead you should use the `$s0`...`$s7`  registers when you want them to be preserved

edit: Oh, I see you also have an error with the order of your instructions, as you said. Also keep in mind the limitations of temporary registers though

Comment: system-call calling conventions are typically different from function-call calling conventions.  e.g. in Linux, system calls *do* preserve all registers (except on some architectures, like x86-64 where the `syscall` instruction always destroys rcx and r11 (to hold the return RIP and RFLAGS), because the kernel stack isn't accessible yet so there's nowhere in memory to save them without making the instruction do even more stuff.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Interesting, but is this is an invariant that you can assume across any kernel? I wouldn't be surprised if a syscall on some embedded system trampled a `$t` register but I *would* be surprised if it trampled an `$s`. Maybe this intuition is faulty.

Comment: You can't assume it without checking, since any kernel is free to do whatever it wants.  Your intuition about which regs an ABI designer would choose as syscall-clobbered sounds good to me.  If I was forced to guess and wasn't allowed to check the docs, I'd code defensively and assume that syscalls clobbered regs that are considered temporary by the standard MIPS conventions.  But I think there's a good chance that they aren't clobbered in SPIM's syscall ABI (or whatever this is).

Comment: Since SPIM is a teaching tool, it really should clobber all of the `$txx` registers to train students in the correct use of the MIPS calling conventions. For some bizarre reason newbie MIPS questioners always use `$txx` for everything instead of `$sxx`.